# Can I create an HTML pop up that do not use Javascript? or can I put the Javascript into the <body> section?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I have to create a pop up that will be show when the user click on a link.

I think that I can not use Javascript because I have no access to the full template so I can't put the javascript into the `<head></head>` section of the page (I can't modify it)

Can I create a pure HTML pop up withous use Javascript or alternatively can I declare my Javascript into the `<body></body>` of my html code and not into the `<head></head>` section?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: This is what the `<dialog>` element is intended for, but it has almost no browser support.

Comment: @Anthony as far as I can tell, `<dialog>` is not about "dialog box" but about "a dialog between a horse and a toad"; that is, [a conversation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-dialog-element).

Comment: That was when `dialog` was a different container for definition lists. It's now : "The dialog element represents a part of an application that a user interacts with to perform a task, for example a dialog box, inspector, or window.” -- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element

Comment: But I do advocate for horse and toad conversations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in pure html and css. The trick is to use the `:target` pseudo selector. Rules with `:target` will match when the url anchor matches a particular id. You can update the url anchor by creating a plain anchor link. This does have a slight jumping effect because we're using anchors, but it is possible.

So for example: http://jsfiddle.net/X49zJ/1/

```
<a href="#modal">Click to Trigger The Modal</a>
<div id="modal"> I am a Hidden Modal</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#modal {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  background:#EEE;
}

#modal:target {
  display: block;
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target for more information on the `:target` and also this [demo](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4607/lightbox.html) for a much prettier lightbox.

For more flexibility you can always add javascript. If your javascript is non-essential, it's generally best practice to put javascript at the bottom of the body, or add the script tag with the async attribute so it doesn't pause rendering of content when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTML and CSS, like [so](http://pauljablonski.net/pure-css-popup-for-any-content.html).

To answer your second question, generally it's possible to put Javascript in the `<body>` section of your page as well.

Comment: This is not possible without javascript.

Comment: @Connor that is simply not true; did you even check the link?  It's limited by browser compatibility, if you care about IE6, and that particular trick is also problematic for touch devices, but there are other ways too.

Comment: @Pointy Ok, i can accept that hacky solution, but there is nothing like that in the link provided by this answer, It's all hover stuff

Comment: A div overlay is not a new window. It's better, but not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Anthony well perhaps, but it's not at all clear what the OP actually wants. Yes, he said "link", but I'm not willing to trust that he's using that term with the intention of being really specific, given the apparent lack of confidence with the problem space.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without javascript, however you can put script tags literally anywhere in your page and it should work, so try this.

```
<div>
   <h1 id="test">New Content</h1>
   <script>
      var test = document.getElementById('test');
      test.addEventListener('click', function() {
         alert('clicked');
      });
   </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's permittable to use `target="_blank"` in the `<a>` tag if you're using HTML5, which will generally make the link open in a new tab in modern browsers. This is preferred by quite a lot of users so you may want to consider this.

Putting JavaScript into the body of the page should be perfectly fine if you have complete control over the HTML. It is put within simple `<script>` tags, after all — there's no need for it to be in the `<head>`.

If whatever CMS you're using filters out `<script>` tags but you still have control over HTML attributes, you might be able to get away with putting JavaScript in an `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'height=200,location=yes,width=350,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">Link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find a walk-through http://dsheiko.com/weblog/fancy-modal-windows-without-javascript/
It opens pop-up and blurs the modal underlay. Here how it looks `codepen.io/dsheiko/pen/jCcld`

It also describes how you can enhance it with such goodies as closing on Esc press and by clicking outside modal content and provides JavaScript fallback for IE8.